# How can I make an exception to /* url-pattern in web.xml?

Tags: java, websphere, web.xml

In our web.xml, we have CXFServlet mapped to the /* url pattern:

```xml
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>CXFServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

This works great and we don't want to change it at this point. But I would like to have an html page (`/admin/index.html`) that is not handled by the CXFServlet, and is just served up directly as html. How can I accomplish this? I don't know how to create a servlet mapping just to serve an html page.

Note we are using IBM WebSphere 8 (WAS 8) if that matters.

Comment: Consider `welcome-file-list` and `welcome-file`

Comment: `welcome-file` does not work; I added a welcome-file of `index.html` but the CXFServlet still handles requests for `/admin` and `/admin/`. It responds with "No service found".

Comment: @MichaelLucas, Yes, you are right. It should be the other way around.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

None of the given answers (so far) met my requirements, but I found a simple solution that did.

For some reason it turns out that WebSphere will handle JSPs itself, rather than delegating to the servlet that has the `/*` mapping -- even though there is no specific mapping in web.xml mentioning JSPs. Maybe this is part of the spec and one would have to explicitly map `*.jsp` to a servlet if you want it to handle those requests?

In any case it works for me -- instead of using `/admin/index.html` I can use `/admin/index.jsp` (and will probably add `index.jsp` to welcome-file-list so that requests for `/admin` will also give this page).

Answer (score 0):

You can try:

```xml
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>CXFServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>default</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/admin/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

It work's in Jetty and Tomcat.

Answer (score 0):

You can have some code in CXFServlet.java

In doget() methods:

```
URL url = new URL(request.getRequestURL());
    System.out.println("URL is:" + url);
if (url.toString().contains("/admin/")) {
        response.setContentType("text/html; charset=UTF-8");
        PrintWriter pw = response.getWriter();
        pw.print("<!DOCTYPE html><html lang=\"fa\" dir=\"rtl\">\n"
                + "<head>"
                + "<meta charset=\"utf-8\"/>"
                + "</head>"
                + "<body>"
                + "<div>some thing</div>"
                + "<body></html>");
        pw.close();
        return;
    }
```

Comment: We did not want to modify CXFServlet.java